# How to conditionally serialize a field

Tags: java, jackson, annotations

I want to conditionally serialize a field.  I figured out how to conditionally ignore a field with

```
public class NologIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        boolean noLogOnClass = m.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(NoLog.class) != null;
        return m.hasAnnotation(NoLog.class) || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m) || noLogOnClass;
    }
}
```

But what I really want to do is to redact the field.  So if I have

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyObject1 {
    public String field1 = "field1";
    @NoLog
    public String field2 = "field2";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new NologIntrospector());
        final MyObject1 myObject1 = new MyObject1();
        System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject1));
    }
}
```

I get

```
{"field1":"field1"}
```

Field2 is correctly ignored.  But what I really want is

```
{"field1":"field1", "field2": "<***redacted***>"}
```

I have another annotation, `@MaskSensitiveData`

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = MaskSensitiveDataSerializer.class)
public @interface MaskSensitiveData {
}

public class MaskSensitiveDataSerializer extends StdSerializer<Object> {

    protected MaskSensitiveDataSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public MaskSensitiveDataSerializer(Class<Object> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (!(value instanceof  String)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("MaskSensitiveData annotation is only valid for string");
        }
        gen.writeString("<*** redacted ***>");
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is combine them.  So if a field has the special annotation and I am using my introspector, only then, do I want to redact the field.  Otherwise, the field should be serialized normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of overriding method `hasIgnoreMarker` in `NologIntrospector`. You need to override `findSerializer`.
This way when your introspector  is enabled the custom serializer will be used else it will use the original serializer.

```
public class NologIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
    @Override
    public Object findSerializer(Annotated ann){
        if (ann.hasAnnotation(NoLog.class)) {
            return MaskSensitiveDataSerializer.class;
        }
        return super.findSerializer(ann);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, thank you.  I only recently learned about JacksonAnnotationIntrospector and I'm amazed at what it can do.  I wish it was a little better documented